# CSS Menu - two lines should remove padding

Tags: html, css

I have a problem I've yet to discover a solution for.
I have a very simple menu: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qsESh/)

As you can see, the first item is centered in the middle due to padding-top, now this is fine but the rest of the items have 2 lines, so the padding pushes them down.

Is there a way to define that "If the item has 2 lines, then remove padding-top"?

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
<ul class="foldoutmenu">
<li class="current menuitem1 firstitem "><a href="/angsthaantering.aspx"><span class="foldoutmenu_title">Angsthåntering</span></a></li>
<li class="menuitem2 "><a href="/haandter-din-depression.aspx"><span class="foldoutmenu_title">Håndter din depression</span></a></li>
<li class="menuitem3 "><a href="/laer-at-leve-med-adhd-som-voksen.aspx"><span class="foldoutmenu_title">Lær at leve med ADHD som voksen</span></a></li>
<li class="menuitem4 "><a href="/styr-din-spiseforstyrrelse.aspx"><span class="foldoutmenu_title">Styr din spiseforstyrrelse</span></a></li>
<li class="menuitem5 lastitem "><a href="/personlig-udvikling-via-musik-og-kunst.aspx"><span class="foldoutmenu_title">Personlig udvikling via musik og kunst</span></a></li>
```

​

CSS:

```
.menu, .menu ul { float: left; width: 100%; background: #464646; height: 41px; border-top: 1px solid #000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; }
.menu ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.menu a { color: #e4e4e4; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px; }
.menu li { float: left; margin: 0px; padding:10px 10px 0 10px; width:170px; height:32px; border-right: 1px solid #000; list-style-type: none; }
.menu li ul { position: absolute; left: -999em; top:42px; left:0; }
.menu li:hover ul { left: 0; }

.menu ul li.current a { text-decoration:none; }
.menu ul li.current { background:#c1001f; }
```

I/ hope my question was clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the items `display: table-cell;` and the parent `table-row`. Then set the `vertical-align: middle;` property:

http://jsfiddle.net/qsESh/1/

If you don't want to items to spread across the whole width of the page, make the `<ul>` element smaller.

Edit: You can also set a `min-width` or `width` to the `<li>` elements to make them bigger. Though like this the menu may be wider than the page itself: http://jsfiddle.net/qsESh/2/

Comment: This actually works pretty good, I'm suprised tbh. I tested it in Chrome, firefox, IE9 and safari, it appears to work just fine (not sure about IE8). Thumps up

Comment: It should work in IE 8+ according to [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html). But I can't test, I don't have a Windows system, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to give a pure **CSS Solution**. But you can do something.

#### Case 1: JavaScript

Find the highest element, apply the height to all. You can do this way:

```
var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $("#menu li").map(function ()
{
    return $(this).height();
}).get());
```

#### Case 2: CSS

Give a `nowrap` and `ellipsis`.

```
.menu a span {width: 100px; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden;}
```

Comment: @MikeBertelsen Updated answer dude. Try it and let me know na?